# Fancybox suddenly stopped working after https my website

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I have a static website on html and css, i add Fancybox code and works fine but recently update my website too HTTPS and Fancybox stop working. 
Any idea what caused this problem? 

Thanks

Comment: please add the code, I suspect you need to add https to your fancy box script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you have not updated the location of JS and CSS files. Anyay, it is not possible to answer properly without seeing your page.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help i double check my code and...
    `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>`

**Just add a https** 
    `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>`

and all solved!